# Spring Kafka - offsetsForTimes method returns null for some partitions

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I use spring-boot 2.2.11, spring-kafka 2.4.11 and apache kafka-clients 2.4.1

I have my consumer `implements ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener`, and I am trying to seek to offsets after certain timestamp inside `onPartitionsAssigned` method by calling `offsetsForTimes`.

I found this strange behavior of method `offsetsForTimes`:

When I seek an earlier timestamp `1607922415534L` (GMT December 14, 2020 5:06:55.534 AM) like below:

```java
@Override
public void onPartitionsAssigned(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
    // calling assignment just to ensure my consumer is actually assigned the partitions
    Set<TopicPartition> tps = consumer.assignment();
    Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> offsetsForTimes = new HashMap<>();
    offsetsForTimes.putAll(consumer.offsetsForTimes(partitions.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(tp -> tp, epoch -> 1607922415534L))));
}
```

By setting breakpoint, I can see I got below map:

```
{TopicPartition@5492} "My.Data.Topic-1" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5493} "(timestamp=1607922521082, leaderEpoch=282, offset=22475886)"
{TopicPartition@5495} "My.Data.Topic-0" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5496} "(timestamp=1607922523035, leaderEpoch=328, offset=25587551)"
{TopicPartition@5498} "My.Data.Topic-5" -> null
{TopicPartition@5500} "My.Data.Topic-4" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5501} "(timestamp=1607924819752, leaderEpoch=323, offset=24578937)"
{TopicPartition@5503} "My.Data.Topic-3" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5504} "(timestamp=1607922522143, leaderEpoch=299, offset=23439914)"
{TopicPartition@5506} "My.Data.Topic-2" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5507} "(timestamp=1607938218461, leaderEpoch=318, offset=23415078)"
{TopicPartition@5509} "My.Data.Topic-9" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5510} "(timestamp=1607922521019, leaderEpoch=298, offset=22002124)"
{TopicPartition@5512} "My.Data.Topic-8" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5513} "(timestamp=1607922520780, leaderEpoch=332, offset=23406692)"
{TopicPartition@5515} "My.Data.Topic-7" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5516} "(timestamp=1607922522800, leaderEpoch=285, offset=22215781)"
{TopicPartition@5518} "My.Data.Topic-6" -> null
```

However, if I seek a more recent timestamp like `1607941818423L` (GMT December 14, 2020 10:30:18.423 AM), I got offsets for all partitions:

```
{TopicPartition@5492} "My.Data.Topic-1" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5493} "(timestamp=1607942934371, leaderEpoch=282, offset=22568732)"
{TopicPartition@5495} "My.Data.Topic-0" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5496} "(timestamp=1607941818435, leaderEpoch=328, offset=25685999)"
{TopicPartition@5498} "My.Data.Topic-5" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5499} "(timestamp=1607941818424, leaderEpoch=309, offset=24333860)"
{TopicPartition@5501} "My.Data.Topic-4" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5502} "(timestamp=1607941818424, leaderEpoch=323, offset=24666385)"
{TopicPartition@5504} "My.Data.Topic-3" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5505} "(timestamp=1607941818433, leaderEpoch=299, offset=23529597)"
{TopicPartition@5507} "My.Data.Topic-2" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5508} "(timestamp=1607941818423, leaderEpoch=318, offset=23431817)"
{TopicPartition@5510} "My.Data.Topic-9" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5511} "(timestamp=1607941818517, leaderEpoch=298, offset=22082849)"
{TopicPartition@5513} "My.Data.Topic-8" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5514} "(timestamp=1607941818423, leaderEpoch=332, offset=23491462)"
{TopicPartition@5516} "My.Data.Topic-7" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5517} "(timestamp=1607942934371, leaderEpoch=285, offset=22306422)"
{TopicPartition@5519} "My.Data.Topic-6" -> {OffsetAndTimestamp@5520} "(timestamp=1607941818424, leaderEpoch=317, offset=24677423)"
```

So I am confused why seeking to an older timestamp gave me nulls when there are indeed messages with later timestamp as I tried in the 2nd time? Is there any search range limit of this call or did I do something wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It simply means there is no committed offset at less than or equal to that timestamp; you can use zero in that case.

Comment: I think offsetsForTimes should return the first message with timestamp "greater than or equal to" the target timestamp, right? Not less.

Comment: Oh; you are right; according to the javadocs. My bad.

Comment: I have a blind guess could it be related to log segment? like when I put an early timestamp it may somehow lead to a search in an old log segment which is cleaned by the retention policy, and hence returns null?

Comment: I have no idea; I took a quick look at the server code, but I don't know Scala well enough to see what's going on. Maybe try asking on one of their [mailing lists](https://kafka.apache.org/contact) or open a JIRA issue.

Comment: thanks Gary. I'll try the mailing list first.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, it *can* return null for partition, if there is no messages in it from specified timestamp. So, if you want to call [`consumer#seek`](https://kafka.apache.org/37/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,long)) for partition, you need to check if it is null, and if it is, call `consumer#seekToEnd` instead.

```scala
        if (offsetAndTimestamp != null) {
          consumer.seek(partition, offsetAndTimestamp.offset)
        } else {
          consumer.seekToEnd(Collections.singletonList(partition))
        }
```